# Email survey monkey survey automatically

Tags: surveymonkey

Is it possible to automatically send a survey to everyone who registers at my website as soon as they are finished with the registration process? As I understand send_flow only sets up a flow and the user still has to send the email through the surverymonkey interface.

Comment: This depends on too many factors. How is your website built? How far can you change it to integrate with whatever surveymoney provides? Do you want a general idea as to how you can do this or a solution for a specific issue you are facing?

Comment: Right now I am looking to get a general idea to figure out if this is even possible.

Comment: Couldn't you just email the user with a link to your survey?  i.e. just use a normal weblink collector.

Comment: I wanted to explore the option of sending the survey as soon as he/she finishes registration process.

Comment: @aui, What Miles is suggesting is that you either email your user who have just signed up an email containing a link to a weblink collector. You could also present the link in your website's UI.

Comment: I would use Examinare instead. There is even functions for email and sms that will make all the flow for you. Also their php wrapper is available and code-samples. So easy

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use the features of send_flow to distribute your invitation via SurveyMonkey's mailer, you can send the email immediately by setting "send" to true in your request to send_flow. The email will send in about 5 minutes as will all email sent from SurveyMonkey.

Using send_flow will create one collector for each request which could get unwieldy in SurveyMonkey's UI, but it will work.

Comment: It didn't really work for me. Emails were sent, but the collector was still in "Not Configured" state and clicking link in the email was taking me to a page saying survey is not active. Only activating collector by hand in UI made previously sent links working.

Comment: All new email collectors are "not configured" until they are scheduled to be sent. This is true even if the collector is created through SurveyMonkey's user interface. What you're seeing is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to check out Examinare instead? You can with less than 10 code rows do this by combining the following functions:

Create the recipient:
https://developer.examinare.com/apidocs/addrecipient/

Send the email with the created ID:
https://developer.examinare.com/apidocs/sendsurvey/

I bet if you contact Examinare support email you will get help from them.